# I am getting another kendo window at background

Tags: html, kendo-ui

[image: This is Screenshot of form and I am getting rectangle behind form]

```
<div class="red">
<kendo-dialog class="form-title-bar" (close)="onCancel($event)" [title]="formTitle" *ngIf="visible">
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSaveClick($event)" class="well user-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="name">Holiday Name:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Holiday" [attr.disabled]="form.get('name')?.disabled ? true : null" required />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="date">Date:</label>
      <input type="date" formControlName="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="type">Holiday Type:</label>
      <input type="text" formControlName="type" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter type of holiday" required />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button kendoButton type="button" (click)="onCancel($event)" class="btn btn-secondary">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>&nbsp;Cancel
    </button>
    <button kendoButton type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      <i class="fa-regular fa-floppy-disk"></i> &nbsp;Submit
    </button>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="warningMessage" class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ warningMessage }}
  </div>
</form>
```